# Angular FormArray. Getting the field key dynamically

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

I developed a Reactive Form, and one of its fields is a FormArray that might contain extra fields added by a user in order to customize the form. I was able to get it working

Form: Ts file:

```
this.orderForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    ....
    customFields: this.formBuilder.array([])
  });
```

Template:

```
<div formArrayName="customFields" *ngFor="let item of orderForm.get('customFields').controls; let i = index;">
    <div class="form-group" [formGroupName]="i">
        <label for="department">department</label>
        <input id="department" name="department" formControlName="department" class="form-control" type="text" autocomplete="off" aria-label="department"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've added items to the FormArray using the FormBuilder.group method using this syntax:

```
this.formBuilder.group({
    department: ''
  });
```

Due to the fact that I will only have one FormArray in the form, I would like to know how to get the "department" key manually instead of adding it manually, something like this:

```
<div formArrayName="customFields" *ngFor="let item of orderForm.get('customFields').controls; let i = index;">
    <div class="form-group" [formGroupName]="i">
        <label for="{{item.key}}">{{item.key}}</label>
        <input id="{{item.key}}" name="{{item.key}}" formControlName="{{item.key}}" class="form-control" type="text" autocomplete="off"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is that possible? I was reading and trying to find an answer but I didn't succeed.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: I see no `formArray` anywhere, where do you initialize it?

Comment: @MaximeLafarie I've updated the example. Thanks :)

Comment: Ok thanks! :) I'm trying to reproduce your example, but I would like to know what go into your formarray?

Comment: @MaximeLafarie you can try to inject into the formarray the formbuilder.group (the one containing the 'department' key). So, you have a form, that can be customized by adding new fields coming from an injector.
The key of the question is if it's possible to get the formName based on the key that we're providing to the formbuilder.group, (eg: department: '') because the angular form knows that every input field name property should match a field present on the formbuilder.